# How to apply a device tree blob overlay on MSC SM2S IMX8PLUS

Tags: linux, yocto, u-boot, hdmi, imx8

I try to apply a device tree blob (overlay-hdmi.dtb provided in the build output) with UBOOT on an AVNET MSC SM2S IMX8PLUS system with QT5 following the [UBOOT instructions](https://u-boot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/fdt_overlays.html#manually-loading-and-applying-overlays) to activate the HDMI interface.

Unfortunately this does not work as expected. I receive the following message line during the boot process.

```
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: console=ttymxc1,115200 root=/dev/mmcblk1p2 rootwait rw dtb-module=msc-sm2s-imx8mp-24N0600I-module.dtb dtb-overlay=undefined loglevel=7
```

Any idea how to set the DTB overlay properly to activate the HDMI interface?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I followed the simple steps below. No need for using the UBOOT instructions.

1. `setenv fdt_overlay overlay-hdmi.dtb`
2. set the display info with the proper interface and resolution

   `setenv displayinfo 'video=mxcfb0:dev=hdmi,1920x1080M@60,if=RGB24'`
3. `saveenv`
4. `boot`

Afterwards I recognized that the Kernel command line in the boot process changed.

```
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: console=ttymxc1,115200 root=/dev/mmcblk1p2 rootwait rw dtb-module=msc-sm2s-imx8mp-24N0600I-module.dtb dtb-overlay=overlay-hdmi.dtb loglevel=7
```

Furthermore the monitor connected via HDMI and displayed the expected output.